# Problema com o projeto WPF no Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, wpf

Olá, estou com um problema no Visual Studio e gostaria de saber se alguém tem uma solução. Eu criei uma nova Window WPF:

```
public  partial class CadastroCobertura: Window  { (...)}
```

porém essa classe para manter a lógica do programa deve ser herdada por outra classe chamada CadastroGenerico, essa classe CadastroGenerico herda de Window e então eu alterei a classe CadastroCobertura para que ela ficasse assim:

```
public  partial class CadastroCobertura : CadastroGenerico { (...)}
```

o problema é que as classes de Windows do WPF são divididas em duas partes, e a outra parte também deveria ser alterada então eu fiz a alteração:

```
public partial class CadastroCobertura : CadastroGenerico, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector
```

porém toda vez que eu compilo o programa ele muda para a forma inicial da classe:

```
public partial class CadastroCobertura : System.Windows.Window, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector
```

isso ocorre pois essa classe secundaria é gerada automaticamente pelo Visual Studio. Eu percebo aqui uma limitação do Visual Studio em não perceber que eu desejo modificar minha classe, e como eu não consigo modifica-la meu programa não funciona. Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como alterar isso, ou sabem como eu posso emitir recado para a microsoft? Desde já agradeço =)